# Llisten for multiple events in socket.io

Tags: javascript, events, socket.io, coffeescript, dom-events

I would like to display to the user the state the socket.io connection is in.  To do that I have a bunch of these to tell the user.

```
#I can't use `*` because I have some customized events
socket.on 'my_command', =>
    set_status "connecting"

socket.on 'connecting', =>
    set_status "connecting"

socket.on 'disconnect', =>
    set_status "disconnect"

socket.on 'connect_failed', =>
    set_status "connect_failed"
```

Is there a way to compress all these down to something smaller?  Something like:

```
socket.on 'connecting, disconnect, connect_failed', (name_of_event)=>
    set_status name_of_event
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that **socket.io** doesn't provide such short hand bindings. You can write it in a for loop.

```js
for event in ['connecting', 'disconnect', 'connect_failed']
  do (event) =>
    socket.on event, =>
      set_status event

# or
for event in 'connecting, disconnect, connect_failed'.split(/,\s*/)
  do (event) =>
    socket.on event, =>
      set_status event
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Socket.IO v3, Catch-all listeners were introduced :

```
socket.onAny((eventName, ...args) => {
  // ...
});
```

you can add conditional logic inside the listener for different cases.

check the official documentation for further information : [catch-all listeners](https://socket.io/docs/v4/listening-to-events/#catch-all-listeners)